# how can initialize size of blocking queue with ArrayBlockingQueue<String>() to show get msg in another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, blockingqueue

```
BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(10);

for(int i=0; i<queue.size(); i++){
    queue[i] = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>();
}

System.out.println("queue size in main "+queue.size());

***// queue.size() returning 0 why???***

Thread t2 = new Thread(new AccountTransaction(queue));
t2.start();
Thread t1 = new Thread(new BankInfo(queue));
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you add some more context to your question? What are you trying to get work that's not working?

Comment: I am trying to get msg through queue.take() when condition match with data that is also getting from take() method. means wanna execute blocks of code in one thread on condition matched of take() method.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing your `queue` as an `ArrayBlockingQueue`, but referencing it later as an array of `BlockingQueue`s.

That won't compile.

On top of that, the `size` method will return the number of items in the queue, not its capacity (which you set in the constructor).

When you reference `queue.size()` in your code it will return `0`, as there are no items in the queue.

Comment: how is it raw-typed? when i am using BlockingQueue<String>.
Please let clear my doubt as i am beginner..
Thank U Mena!!!

Comment: @GeekAbhiGeek looks like you edited your post... I'll remove the reference to raw types in my answer.

Comment: I dint edit my post. Could you please tell me If In first thread i am putting a object in blockingQueue and want to execute multiple block of code of second thread based on switch:case condition.Also having some another take() method in these blocks of code.
how could i do that.
Please tell with some peace of code.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the condition of the for loop, when you call queue.size() it returns zero and the loop terminates without running the body. The output of the System.out.println() also calls queue.size() which is still zero. Try using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#remainingCapacity()

@mena also mentioned that you are using queue -- a collection -- as if it is an array which is a compile error.